# How I can get JSON data using javascript and based on the input provided?

Tags: javascript

How I can get my JSON data using javascript and based on the input provided?

My JSON file looks below...

```
{
    "Name1": {
        "id": "32313",
        "latitude": "57.1",
        "longitude": "9.85",
        "timezone": "2",
        "city": "Aalborg",
        "country": "Denmark",
        "country_code": "DK"
    },
    "Name2": {
        "id": "32314",
        "latitude": "56.15",
        "longitude": "10.2167",
        "timezone": "2",
        "city": "Aarhus",
        "country": "Denmark",
        "country_code": "DK"
    },
    "Name3": {
        "id": "122109",
        "airport_name": "Aasiaat",
        "latitude": "68.7",
        "longitude": "-52.75",
        "timezone": "-3",
        "city": "Aasiaat",
        "country": "Greenland",
        "country_code": "GL"
    },
    "Name4": {
        "id": "116713",
        "latitude": "30.371111",
        "longitude": "48.228333",
        "timezone": "4",
        "city": "Abadan",
        "country": "Iran",
        "country_code": "IR"
    },
    "Name5": {
        "id": "116711",
        "latitude": "53.74",
        "longitude": "91.385",
        "timezone": "7",
        "city": "Abakan",
        "country": "Russia",
        "country_code": "RU"
    },
    "Name6": {
        "id": "120587",
        "latitude": "49.05",
        "longitude": "-122.2833",
        "timezone": "-7",
        "city": "Abbotsford",
        "country": "Canada",
        "country_code": "CA"
    },
    "Name7": {
        "id": "116759",
        "latitude": "13.847",
        "longitude": "20.844333",
        "timezone": "1",
        "city": "Abeche",
        "country": "Chad",
        "country_code": "TD"
    },
    "Name8": {
        "id": "32325",
        "latitude": "57.2",
        "longitude": "-2.2",
        "timezone": "1",
        "city": "Aberdeen",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "country_code": "GB"
    }
}
```

From the above JSON file... I need to get the following:

1. Get the list of countrys
2. Get the city names based on the country name provided.

Please help me to parse the above JSON file....

Thanks,
Yugandhar

Answer (score 1):

```
var info = {
    "Name1": {
        "id": "32313",
        "latitude": "57.1",
        "longitude": "9.85",
        "timezone": "2",
        "city": "Aalborg",
        "country": "Denmark",
        "country_code": "DK"
    },
    ....
    "Name8": {
        "id": "32325",
        "latitude": "57.2",
        "longitude": "-2.2",
        "timezone": "1",
        "city": "Aberdeen",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "country_code": "GB"
    }
}

//stores countries in an array
var countries = [];
//stores cities in an object keyed on the contrycode
var cities = {};        
var keyNames = {};
for(var prop in ​info){
   var country = info[prop]["country"];
   var country_code = info[prop]["country_code"];
   var cityname = info[prop]["city"];

   countries.push(country);
   var city = cities[country_code];
   if(typeof city == "undefined"){
        cities[country_code] = [];         
   }

   var key = keyNames[country_code];
   if(typeof key == "undefined"){
        keyNames[country_code] = []; 
   }

   cities[country_code].push(cityname);
   keyNames[country_code].push(prop);
}

console.log(cities);
console.log(countries);
```

​

Comment: How to get the key names based on country or city names... for example: getKeyName(Country) should return "Name1/Name2/" like that

Comment: well you dont need to use the country_code as the key unless you want to, you can replace cities[country_code] with cities[country]. If you did want to usee the country_code as the key, just add another global variable called var country_codes = []  and add country_codes.push(country_code);

Comment: Hi... I think i didn't put my question properly... i want to retrieve Name1/ Name2 when the corresponding country code that i provided... if I say Country_Code = "GB" then my return value = "Name8"...

Comment: ahh sorry, I misunderstood, Ive updated my code with a keyNames object

Comment: Hey @YugandharKumar just following up, did that keyNames object work for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
var countries = [];
// Vanilla Javascript
// Get Array of countries
for( var name in json ){
  countries.push(json[name]["country"]);
}
// Get city name based on country name

var getCities =  function(country){
  var cities = [];
  for( var name in json ){
    if (country === json[name]["country"]){
      cities.push(name);
    }
  }
  return cities;
}

// Usage
var cities = getCities("Denmark"); //
```

Answer (score 0):

Underscore.js ( http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/ ) is the swiss army knife of javascript libraries, it is very useful when handling data sets like in this case.

I created a jsfiddle that solves your two use cases http://jsfiddle.net/4NJPc/

Here are the important parts:

```
function getCityData(country) {
    return _(data)
        .filter(function(el) {
            return el.country === country;
        });           
}

function getCountries() {
    return _(data).chain().pluck("country").uniq().value();
}
```